# Computing $\int \frac x{x+4}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I get that you use substitution $u = x+4$ but I don't understand how the numerator/denominator flips and looks like some conjugate stuff happens.

Using an online calculator with steps, it says after substitution, it turns into

$$\int \frac{x-4}{x} \, dx$$

which you can then split into two integrals. What rule flips the numerator/denominator and changes sign?

Comment: Aftwr $u=x+4,$ it doesn't "turn into" $\int \frac{x-4}x\,dx,$ it becomes $\int \frac{u-4}u\,du.$ It ia important to keep the $u$ there, because you will have to replace $u$ with $x+4.$

Comment: If substitution is confusing you, note $\frac{x}{x+4}=\frac{x+4-4}{x+4}=1-\frac{4}{x+4}$. From this you just get $x-4 \log \left ( \left | x+4 \right | \right )+C$ as your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't some deep rule. Define $\color{red}{u=x+4}$. Then $\color{blue}{x=u-4}$. So

$$\int \frac{\color{blue}{x}}{\color{red}{x+4}} \, dx = \int \frac{\color{blue}{u-4}}{\color{red}{u}} \, du$$

It's just finding a way to express every $x$ in the integral in terms of $u$.

Comment: Colors are very helpful to visualize the sustitution!

Answer (score 2):

You are being confused by the reuse of $x$.  If we have $\frac x{x+4}$ and make the substitution $u=x+4, x=u-4$ we get
$$\frac x{x+4}=\frac {u-4}u=1-\frac 4u$$
We didn't flip anything, we just did the substitution.  The second $=$ shows why this helps.  We get two fractions, each of which we know how to integrate.